# Show inputMethod and get keycode on Key pressed Android

Tags: android, listener, android-softkeyboard, keycode, ime

I know that there are some other post asking similar things, but I could not figure it out how to do it.

My situation is the following:

I have a FragmentActivity with few fragments, on of this is a keyboard fragment, when it is selected the Softkeyboard is shown. This I finally discover how to do it without a Edittext

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
        (InputMethodManager) EngelMote.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    imm.showSoftInput(EngelMote.this.findViewById(R.id.actionbar), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Now my next step is to get the keycode that the user press, it's not useful for me to get the letter or whatever.

What I want is the KeyCode, so if the user press the Key "a" I want to get the KeyCode.Key_A

I tried a lot of ways to do it. Override the dispatchKey, implementing the onKeyListener. No way to get the inputkey of the softkeyboard.

Anyone knows how to do it?

thank u

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use EditorActionListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29

Comment: It never come in...
I finally found sth, but the delete key is not doing anything